# is there any law like the 18 U.S. Code § 201 in latinamerican countries?

Tags: criminal-law, argentina, mexico

In many latinamerican countries, legislators and others politicians are receiving benefits to support some laws which favors international companies. I've read that US has the [18 U.S. Code § 201](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/201) where you can go to jail for bribing public officials and witnesses. Are there laws similar to this in latinamerica, and could CEOs of foreing countries be sued for this? They use a proxy mechanism, where they send funds to NGOS, Universities, etc. (this is public information available in the companies's official websites showing their accounting balances) and later these proxy entities give benefits to the legislators and politicians.

Comment: There are similar laws on the books in pretty much every country, although they are rarely enforced in some countries. A different U.S. law prohibits bribes of foreign officials. Suing someone is a different issue than punishing them criminally and lawsuit for bribery are rare since standing to sue is an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Anti-bribery statutes are common throughout the world, including in Latin America.

However, if the law conflicts with the culture, the culture wins. That is to say, if a system is endemically corrupt it is unlikely that such a system can adequately police corruption.